# menuItem Action not executed in a swift app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder, menuitem

I have a swift app for MacOS, and have a menu with sub menuitems. I add the menu from the appdelegate and assign an action via the interface builder, but the target action is never called:

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
if let menu = menu
{
    statusItem?.menu = menu
    menu.delegate = self
}
pauseMenuItem.target = self
pauseMenuItem.action = #selector(pausePressed(_:))
```

We can see from the bullet on the left of IBAction and from the InterfaceBuilder that the link is well done, but whenever I press on the corresponding menuitem, the action is not executed:
[image]

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are the `NSMenuDelegate` methods called? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Try add action and target in AppDelegate programmatically and test again. I don't see any specific errors in your code and even checked on my laptop, everything should work

Comment: yes, menuWillOpen and menuDidClose are called (they are in the same AppDelegate class). I have updated the question to show explicit action and target setting, but still same issue :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the menu programmatically and it worked:

```
let menu = NSMenu()

let pauseButton = NSMenuItem(title: "Pause", action: #selector(pausePressed), keyEquivalent: "")
menu.addItem(pauseButton)
```

Comment: The right decision. I don't know why the Interface Builder solution didn't work

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but `pausePressed` is called. A IB solution can work.